# No such file or directory: 'logo.PNG'

Tags: python

I am running Python 3.7.0
When I run my Python code from my C drive -> In my C drive, I have a folder with the py code, the word document, and the logo. The three items are located in the same folder.

Summary:

1-When I run the code from my computer. It runs perfectly. 
2-When I run the code from an Application (This Application runs locally from my computer) pointing to the path where my python code is stored. The code starts to run perfectly except when the code reaches this line doc.add_picture('logo.PNG').  I receive the following exception:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pythin_docx-0.8.7-py3.7.egg\docx\image\image.py",
>   line46, in from_file with open(path, 'rb') as f: FileNotFoundError:
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logo.PNG'

I am trying to update a WORD document using Python directly from an application

```
import docx
import cx_Oracle
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

try:
    doc = Document()

    Part_No = input("Please enter part_no:  ")

    print(Part_No)
    doc.add_picture('logo.PNG')
    doc.add_heading('Part Change Notification', 0)
    doc.add_paragraph('Part Number: '+ ' '+Part_No)
    doc.save('testing.docx')    

    input("Your Part_No: " +Part_No+" has been updating it on the word document.")

except BaseException:
    import sys
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
    print("Document was updated it")
    input()
    input(20)
```

Comment: And what is the current working directory in each case?  See [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```py
doc.add_picture('logo.PNG')
```

try:

```py
doc.add_picture(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logo.PNG'))
```

This will make sure the PNG is next to the python script.

Also, don't use uppercase.

Comment: Jorjon...Man...You are the best. Thanks. How can I give A+ in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete path instead of just "logo.PNG"

Ex. doc.add_picture('C:/Users/logo.PNG')